# Weird behaviour of typedef and pointers to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Let's say I implement a tree in following way:

```
struct Node;
typedef struct Node Tree
struct Node {
int value;
Tree *left;
Tree *right;
};
```

Now i wanted to experiment with pointers to struct:

```
const Tree * a;
```

This works completely fine, I couldnt assign the value pointed by a to anything else, etc. However, I wanted to make things easier and changed typedef to following:

```
typedef struct Node * Tree
```

And now, even though it seems obvious that

```
const Tree a;
```

should behave the same way the previous declaration did, it doesnt, instead it behaves like a const pointer, meaning i cant write

```
a = ..stmh_else..
```

Why is that happening? Is it some nuance with typedef that I dont know?

Comment: "*However, I wanted to make things easier*" <- don't, just .... don't. Hiding pointers behind `typedef` is one of the worse ways to obfuscate code.

Comment: `const struct Node *` != `struct Node * const`

Comment: Bottom line, no, it shouldn't perform the same way.  The `typedef` ends up acting sort of like parentheses.  When you say `const Tree a;`, the compiler doesn't "peek inside" of `Tree` to discover that it involves a pointer, it just applies the `const` to `a`.